# ReactJS: React-Month-Picker Error: Function components cannot have refs. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `"react": "^16.12.0"` version in that, I made 2 separate screens, One is with React component-based and other is function-based.

In React-component based screen month picker is working for me as shown below,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Picker from 'react-month-picker';
import 'react-month-picker/css/month-picker.css';
import MonthBox from './MonthPicker';

class OldScreen extends Component{
state = { 
    Durtn: "",
    monthValue: {year: new Date().getFullYear(), month: (new Date().getMonth())},
    FormatedMonth:"",
  }
  selectDuration(){
  console.log("Generate")  
  // this.setState({Durtn: "Dur"});
  }      
  handleClickMonthBox(e) {
    this.refs.pickAMonth.show()
  }
  handleAMonthChange(year, month) {
    let Dur = {year: year, month:month}
    this.setState( {monthValue: Dur} )
  }
  handleAMonthDissmis(value) {
      this.setState( {monthValue: value} )
  }

  render(){

      const pickerLang = {
        months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      }
        ,mvalue = this.state.monthValue
      let makeText = m => {
          if (m && m.year && m.month) return (pickerLang.months[m.month-1] + '. ' + m.year)
          return '?'
      }

      return(
        <div style={{ padding:15}}>
        <form>
        <div className="form-row" style={{ paddingTop:20}}>
            <div className="edit" style={{width:100,paddingLeft:10}}>
                <Picker
                    ref="pickAMonth"
                    years={[2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021,2022]}
                    value={mvalue}
                    lang={pickerLang.months}
                    onChange={this.handleAMonthChange.bind(this)}
                    onDismiss={this.handleAMonthDissmis.bind(this)}
                >
                    <MonthBox value={makeText(mvalue)} onClick={this.handleClickMonthBox.bind(this)} />
                </Picker>
              </div>
          </div>
        </form>
     </div>
      )
  }

}
export default OldScreen;
```

Then I tried the same screen with React function-based and it got this error,

```
Error: Function components cannot have refs. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

To Solve this action attempted are,
     1. Because I am using 16.12.0 I have added `import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';` but after added this also i am getting error `TypeError: pickAMonth.show is not a function`

Error Program below,

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

import Picker from 'react-month-picker';
import 'react-month-picker/css/month-picker.css';
import MonthBox from './MonthPicker';




function NewScreen() {
    const pickAMonth = useRef(null);

    const pickerLang = {months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']}
    const mvalue ={year: new Date().getFullYear(), month: (new Date().getMonth())}
      let makeText = m => {if (m && m.year && m.month) return (pickerLang.months[m.month-1] + '. ' + m.year)
                           return '?'}

const handleAMonthChange=(e)=> {
  }
const handleAMonthDissmis=(e)=> {
}
const handleClickMonthBox=(e)=> {
    pickAMonth.show()
  }

    return (
        <div style={{ padding:15}}>
            <form>

            <div className="form-row" style={{ paddingTop:20}}>
                <div className="edit" style={{width:100,paddingLeft:10}}>
                <Picker
                    ref={pickAMonth}
                    years={[2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021,2022]}
                    value={mvalue}
                    lang={pickerLang.months}
                    onChange={handleAMonthChange}
                    onDismiss={handleAMonthDissmis}
                >
                    <MonthBox value={makeText(mvalue)} onClick={handleClickMonthBox} />
                </Picker>
            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NewScreen;
```

Thanks in advance for your time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use ref in react, you need to pass a callback to ref in your componets

**dont**

```js
ref="pickAMonth"
// or
 ref={pickAMonth}
```

**do**

```js
ref = {(componentRef) => refVariable = componentRef
}

ref = {ref => pickAMonth = ref}

// somwhere in your code, now you can do this
pickAMonth.show();
```

Comment: `ref={(pickAMonth)=> pickAMonth.current.show() = pickAMonth}`   and
 `                 `ref={(pickAMonth)=> {
                        pickAMonth.current.show();
                    }}`                         
             I tried this but getting an error!      TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Comment: I tried this and it showed me this error in,    `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable`.     and also I tried the same in OldScreen program also there too I got below error    `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Comment: your pickAMonth is a contant, change it to let type of variable

Comment: Can I know why `ref={pickAMonth}` is in don's..?

Comment: becuse ref expects a function to revice not a variable

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In functional components ref have their values in 'current' property

```
const handleClickMonthBox=(e)=> {
    pickAMonth.**current**.show()
}
```

Comment: Thanks.! this works for me...        

`const handleClickMonthBox=(e)=> {
    pickAMonth.current.show()
  }`

Comment: Great, can you mark the answer as chosen one, it'd help others too.